# Opposite of \allowdisplaybreaks

Tags: page-breaking, amsmath

If i load the `amsmath` package it doesn't allows to break by default alignments across the pages in the  `multline`, `align`, `gather`, `alignat` environments and their starred versions.

Howewer it exists the **global declaration** `\allowdisplaybreaks` (or `\allowdisplaybreaks[1-4]`) allowing breaks. This declaration can be placed in the *preamble* of the document or in *anywhere* of the document from which it has the effect.

Suppose you want to cancel this effect later in the document (reset to default) thereafter, Is there a **global declaration** opposite to `\allowdisplaybreaks` to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `\allowdisplaybreaks` macro changes the `\interdisplaylinepenalty` parameter. You can undo the effect of `\allowdisplaybreaks` using

```
\interdisplaylinepenalty=10000
```

Try commenting `\interdisplaylinepenalty=10000` in the example below to see the effect.

```
\documentclass{article}
\addtolength\textheight{1cm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]
\interdisplaylinepenalty=10000
\begin{align*}
a &= b \\
  &= c \\
  &= d \\
  &= e
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Or there is the simpler way: `\allowdisplaybreaks[0]`.

Comment: Thanks!, i defined something like `\newcommand{\noallowdisplaybreaks}{\interdisplaylinepenalty=10000}` and it works perfect!

Comment: Watching the definition of `\allowdisplaybreaks` in `amsmath.sty` seems that `\interdisplaylinepenalty=10000` is equivalent to `\allowdisplaybreaks[0]` and it also works.