# Creating a new environment that combines samepage with align

Tags: environments, page-breaking

I want to avoid pagebreaks within an `align` environment.
I can accomplish this with both the `samepage` and the `minipage` environments.
However, when I try to create a new environment that combines `align` with 
either one I get errors.    The following illustrates; as far as I can see, my 
use of the `newenvironment` command is completely standard.    Yet both
my new environments `SPalignOne` and `SPalignTwo` throw the ame error, i.e.,
`LaTeX Error: \begin{align} on input line 26 ended by \end{SPalignTwo}`
Could somebody please explain what I'm doing wrong?   Thanks very much, Leo

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newenvironment{SPalignOne}
    {\begin{samepage}\begin{align}}
    {\end{align}\end{samepage}}
\newenvironment{SPalignTwo}
    {\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}\begin{align}}
    {\end{align} \end{minipage} }
\begin{document}
\begin{samepage}
\begin{align}
x
\end{align}
\end{samepage}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{align}
x
\end{align}
\end{minipage}
\begin{SPalignOne}
x
\end{SPalignOne}
\begin{SPalignTwo}
x
\end{SPalignTwo}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs because of the way that the `align` environment processes the material in its scope: LaTeX is set to look ahead for the hard-coded string `\end{align}`, at which point processing of the material in the `align` environment begins in earnest.

With your definitions of the `SPalignX` environments, after `\begin{align}` LaTeX will eventually come across `\end{SPalignX}`; however, it isn't set to evaluate immediately what goes on at the end of an `SPalignX` environment -- and thereby notice that the first instruction to be executed would be `\end{align}`. Hence the error message: LaTeX has encountered the end of an environment (`SPalignX`) before the one it's currently in (`align`) is closed.

Incidentally, by default no page breaks should occur inside an `align` environment, *unless* an instruction such as `\allowdisplaybreaks` was provided. You may want to check the code in your document to discover if such a command is lurking somewhere. It should be easier to cure the problem at its root rather than to provide a treatment of the symptoms, right?

Comment: Thanks, I do have `\allowdisplaybreaks` on in my default preamble, and don't want to turn it off.    I'll use `\allowdisplaybreaks[0]` as recommended in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195592/opposite-of-allowdisplaybreaks